# Error: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho um código JavaScript que retorna valores de um PHP e monta uma tabela HTML. Está dando o erro **Cannot read property 'each' of undefined**. Eu olhei várias vezes sem sucesso. Poderiam me dar uma mão? Segue o código:

**JavaScript:**

```js
function getListaItems(idprojeto) {
  //alert(idprojeto);
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get-lista-items.php?idprojeto=" + idprojeto,
  //data: dataEvento,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(resposta) {
   var str_html = '';
   $.each(resposta, function(){
    str_html = str_html + '<tr class="gradeA" id="' + this.id + '">' +
        '<td class="center"><input type="checkbox"  id="item[]" name="item[]" onchange="changeColor(' + this.id + ')" value="' + this.id + '" /></td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descricao + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descCategoria + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descCaracteristica + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descMedida + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center"><input type="text" id="qtd' + this.id + '" style="width:80px"/></td>' +
        '</tr>';
   });

   document.getElementById("resultJs").innerHTML = str_html;
  }
 });
}
```

**PHP:**

```html
<?php

 session_start();
 require_once("ProjectIncludes.php");

 $service = new ProjetoxItensService();
 $consulta = $service->getAll($_GET['idprojeto']);

 $retorno = json_encode($consulta);
 echo $retorno;

?>
```

Obrigada desde já.

Comment: Já verificou se seu json não está vindo vazio na requisição ajax?

Comment: Sim. Já verifiquei. Vem certinho.

Comment: Aparentemente $ está indefinido, em algum lugar da página o $ é setado como undefined ou é feito um delete encima do mesmo?

Comment: Já descobri o problema. Substituí **$** que vem na frente do **each** por **jQuery**.

Answer (score 3):

Use `jQuery.each` em vez de `$.each`. Pelo visto o alias `$` não existe no seu programa.

Comment: Obrigada. Já tinha encontrado a solução em outro fórum. Mesmo assim, agradeço.